# Modifying data.table columns by index

Tags: r, data.table

I'm not able to understand why the below does not work:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars) 
colnum <- grep("disp", tolower(colnames(dt)))
# 3

dt[, colnum, with = F] <- dt[, colnum, with = F]*2
```

The above throws an error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , colnum, with = F, value = list(disp = c(320,  : 
  unused argument (with = F)
```

Removing `with = F` for the second term also outputs an error:

```
dt[, colnum, with = F] <- dt[, colnum] * 2

Error in `[.data.table`(q, , colnum) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'colnum' is not found. 
Perhaps you intended DT[,..colnum] or DT[,colnum,with=FALSE]. 
This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Why doesn't this work? The above is only a simplified example, but I want to perform more complex manipulation on the `data.table` columns.

Comment: You need something like `dt[, (colnum) := lapply(.SD, '*', 2), .SDcols = colnum][]`

Comment: What about just `dt[,(colnum):=dt[,colnum, with = F]*2]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tried but didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @Jaap it works, thanks! Is there a good source for learning more about `.SDcols` and `.SD`?

Comment: I've included two links in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data.table`-way of doing this is [*updating by reference*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) as follows:

```
 dt[, (colnum) := lapply(.SD, '*', 2), .SDcols = colnum][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
>  1: 21.0   6 320.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
>  2: 21.0   6 320.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
>  3: 22.8   4 216.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
>  4: 21.4   6 516.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
>  5: 18.7   8 720.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
>  6: 18.1   6 450.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> .....
> ```

You can find more info on the [*Getting started*](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) page.